# Can you explain this statement and mathematically verify if it's correct?

Tags: probability, independence

"“A nuclear attack is inevitable. It’s the ultimate problem of mankind. If there’s a ten percent probability that something will happen in a year, there’s a 99.5 percent probability that it will happen in fifty years. But if you can get that probability down to three percent, that reduces the probability to only seventy-eight percent in fifty years. And if you can get it down to one percent, there is only a forty percent probability in fifty years. That’s a truly worthwhile goal—it could literally make all the difference in the world.”

Comment: To calculate the numbers you can use counter-probability. For example: if you know the chance for sunshine tomorrow is p = 0.1 you know the chance for not sunshine is (1-p) = 0.9. We are looking for the counter probability for "an event - the nuclear attack  - wont happen within the next 50 years". Because the counter probability for this statement gives us the probability for the event to happen at least once within the 50 years. 
The formular therefor is: 1-0.9^50 = 99.48%; 1-0.97^50 = 78.19%; 1-0.99^50 = 39.49%. So thats the chance for event happening once ore more often, not exactly once.

Comment: For the introduction Statement, there is this phrase: " that it will happen in fifty years." that makes things unclear. 
The results stated within and after this phrase actually fit for "that it will happen within the next fity years at least once". 
"that it will happen in 50 years" could mean i want to know p for event in exactly 50 years (which would be 0.1 as long as p per year doesn't change). 
But maybe thats just because of my bad english - maybe the meaning of the statement is unambigous :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to calculate the probability of an event *ever* happening is to instead think of the problem as the probability of *no event happening ever*.

If there is a 10% probability for some event, then the probability of it not happening is 90%.

The probability of a 10%-per-year event not happening in 2 consecutive years is .9 * .9 = 81% (so, a 19% chance of the event happening at some point). The probability of a 10%-per-year event happening after 50 years then is the cumulative probability of 50 years of no-event: .9^50 = .005. Therefore a 99.5% chance of happening.

1-.90^50 = 99.5%

1-.97^50 = 78%

1-.99^50 = 40%

So these numbers from the statement are correct.

However, estimating the actual annual percent risk is quite tricky. The statement

> *A nuclear attack is inevitable*

depends heavily on what the actual annual risks are, the time frame that one considers, and how that risk changes with passing years of non-nuclear weapons usage (i.e., if the probability is not independent over time). It's also quite unlikely that the true risk is anything close to constant: during the peak Cold War years the use of nuclear weapons was seriously considered and on a couple occasions came very close to use. Basic statistical probabilities aren't much use to us here.

Comment: +1, though it would be helpful to mention that this only holds for [tag:independence], which is doubtful in this scenario.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I don't think independence is particularly important for this specific problem; the real problem is in estimating that annual risk with any sort of certainty, and in assuming that the risk is constant. I'll mention it briefly though.

Comment: That might make for an interesting discussion. Considering that we can't interpret the probabilities here in a frequentist way, only in a Bayesian one, I would say that having gone through the Cuban Missile Crises should mean that all later probabilities should be lower, though probably not the ones before, so independence looks dubious to me. YMMV.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think I make clear that the risk is unlikely to be anything close to constant. I do agree that passing through the Cuban Missile Crisis without a nuclear exchange would adjust the estimates of risk, but I think that isn't just because of an actual reduction in risk due to non-use, but also a recognition that the previous assumed risk may have been too high. I just don't think stats arguments make much sense when the underlying model is so uncertain.